# bndtools Activator bundle

Tags: osgi, bnd, bndtools

How can I create a simple bundle with an Activator in bndtools?
It keeps saying that:

```
The JAR is empty: The instructions for the JAR named com.myproj did not cause any content to be included, this is likely wrong  bnd.bnd /com.myproj Unknown Bndtools Problem Marker
Unused Private-Package instructions, no such package(s) on the class path: [com.myproj] bnd.bnd /com.myproj Unknown Bndtools Problem Marker
```

The way I create this project in Eclipse is:

1. Create new "Bndtools OSGi project"
2. Right click, configure - Convert to Maven project
3. Create `Activator.java` in package `com.myproj`.
4. Add `com.myproj` to private packages
5. Set activator to `com.Activator`

Here is my bnd file:

```
Bundle-Activator: com.myproj.Activator
Private-Package: com.myproj
```

My generated jar is empty. Any tips?

P.S.: Here is my eclipse project (exported as a zip-archive) in case it sheds any light on things: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9162958/scraper.zip

Comment: Are you creating the jar with maven or via eclipse?

Comment: It seems like your classes (including the activator) are not getting included in your bundle when you export. open your manifest editor click on build which opens the build.properties file and paste that content.

Comment: for example, this is the contents I have in one of my bundle build.properties Does yours look similiar? 
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml,\
               schema/,\
               OSGI-INF/
source.. = src/

Comment: Can you successfully build a bundle workout bndtools? Are you using the maven Tycho plugin?

Comment: @DuncanKrebs Which manifest do you mean? My project doesn't have one. Also, I have no `build.properties` file either. @mbelow I am not using Tycho. I am using bndtools to build it - I mean _it_ builds it automatically for me and places it into `generated` folder.

Comment: I've uploaded my project if it helps to explain my problem...

Comment: I think each one of the previous answers seems to miss the point that drozzy is trying to build with bndtools, not Eclipse. That is, bndtools does not have build.properties (thank god!)

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that "Convert to Maven project" is the trouble. This likely has changed the Eclipse classpath for the project from the bnd default bin folder to 'target/classes'. Can you confirm that it works without converting to maven?

bnd can work with other places for the bin folder, you must set the `${bin}` property (preferably in `cnf/build.bnd`). There are some writeups how to use bndtools with maven. The reason that bnd does not follow Eclipse's settings here is that they are not available without Eclipse and a design goal of bnd is that it builds anywhere: the bnd file must therefore be the final arbiter of information.

Anyway one more tip ... activators are not the right way to build OSGi builds since they are an evil singleton. Declarative services is far superior and we should actually have used a similar mechanism when we designed OSGi.

Answer (score 1):

### My setup:

- Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 (20140612-0600)
- Bndtools 2.3.0.REL-20140510-023245

### Here is how I made it work:

1. I downloaded you exported `scraper.zip`.
2. Created and **empty** workspace in Eclipse.
3. Imported your project from the ZIP archive into the empty workspace.
4. The default `cnf` project was automatically created.
5. By default, `bnd` is configured to use the `bin` directory for compiled `*.class` files while your Eclipse project is configured to use `target/classes`. Therefore, I had to change this settings in `cnf/build.bnd` by adding a single line:

```
########################
## BND BUILD SETTINGS ##
########################
bin: target/classes
```

6. Now, after cleaning and rebuilding the project, `bnd` creates `generated/scraper.jar` that contains your `Activator.class`.

### Notes:

- You could also adapt your project configuration to use the `bin` directory instead of `target/classes` but I assume that you will use Maven later on.
- When using `bndtools`, it sometimes helps when you start with an empty workspace and import your projects one-by-one.
- There is a bug in bndtools 2.4 which causes some problems if there are multiple source directories per project. Therefore, I'm still using version 2.3